# "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ProgramData\DroidExplorer\assets\[DEFAULT].png'" error message when trying to run Droid Explorer

Tags: installation, droid-explorer

I installed Droid Explorer. When trying to run it, I got an error that says

> [image]
>
> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\ProgramData\DroidExplorer\assets[DEFAULT].png'.

I put it manually at `/ProgramData` folder, but it doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: I noticed there's a slightly different path on `/DroidExlorer/` (the error message, without space) and `/Droid Explorer/` (yours, with space)

Answer (score 0):

Install Droid Explorer

Copy all the contents of c:\program files\droid explorer folder

Go into c:\programdata folder

Create a new subfolder: droidexplorer

Paste the contents into this new folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).